# Python refusing to import

Tags: python

First time asking.
Anyways, Python seems to be acting very weird. A while ago, I made a program that imports a variable from another file (part of a larger project). To demonstrate:

```
item.py
class item():
def __init__(self,name,desc,val,dmg,dur):
    s = ''
    self.name = name
    self.desc = desc
    self.val = val
    self.dmg = dmg
    self.dur = dur
rshckey = item('Key to Nowhere','An ancient key, rusted and corroded, that is said to unlock any door.',0,0,1)

data.py
from item import *
print (rshckey)
```

Which gave me this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Chrispang/Google Drive/Python Code/My Projects/Wyvern Caves/Wy4 Riv/data.py", line 2, in <module>
print (rshckey)
NameError: name 'rshckey' is not defined
```

Can anyone explain this? I tried

```
from item import rshckey
```

which gave me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Chrispang/Google Drive/Python Code/My Projects/Wyvern Caves/Wy4 Riv/data.py", line 1, in <module>
from item import rshckey
ImportError: cannot import name 'rshckey'
```

Funny thing was, up to a few days ago it still worked fine.

Comment: Sure the paths to the files are correct?

Comment: they're all in the same file

Comment: and it's worked before so...

Comment: Did you try simply `import item`?

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect in `item.py`. Is `rshckey` actually part of the class `item`?

Comment: That is why you might want to dubble check the path. Things don't just stopped working. Also, try setting a path without spaces!

Comment: Path without spaces?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't indented the __init__ function, your code should look like:

```
item.py
class item():
    def __init__(self,name,desc,val,dmg,dur):
        s = ''
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.val = val
        self.dmg = dmg
        self.dur = dur
rshckey = item('Key to Nowhere','An ancient key, rusted and corroded, that is said to unlock any door.',0,0,1)

data.py
from item import *
print (rshckey)
```